# What is the difference between these two snippets

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I have a doubt. I want to automate adding different products to cart using cypress. I am learning cypress for my project and I have taken a course on Udemy. In the course the instructor used an approach and I created my own, but mine didn't given the desired output. These are the two approaches:

Mine:

```js
cy.get('h4[class="card-title"]')
  .should("have.length", 4)
  .each(($el, index, $list) => {
    cy.contains(product_name)
      .should("be.visible")
      .and("have.text", product_name);
    cy.get("button.btn.btn-info").eq(index).click();
    cy.wrap($el).should("have.text", items[index]);
  });
```

O/P:
[image]

Instructor's:

```js
this.data.product.forEach((product_name) => {
  cy.selectProduct(product_name);
});
```

command.js:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("selectProduct", (productName) => {
  cy.get("h4.card-title").each(($el, index, $list) => {
    if ($el.text().includes(productName)) {
      cy.get("button.btn.btn-info").eq(index).click();
    }
  });
});
```

Why does mine produce the incorrect output?

Comment: What is `product_name` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading up on [`.each()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each) to get a better understanding. The command will iterate over an array like structure so it will do all the commands for each card. There is a mistake in using `index` when clicking the add button when each card only contains one add button.

Here is a more concise way of doing it.

```js
const product_names = [
  'iphone X', 
  'Samsung Note 8',
  'Nokia Edge',
  'Blackberry'
]
cy.get('.card')
  .should('have.length', 4)
  .each(($el, index) => {
    cy.contains(product_names[index])
      .should('be.visible')
    cy.contains('button', /add/i)
      .should('be.visible')
      .click()
})
```

Working [example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/blob/main/cypress/e2e/addToCartCards.js).